# verify checkmark in iOS instruments

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, instruments

I'm trying to verify if a cell has a **checkmark** next to it after being selected through iOS automation of an app.

Can someone help me with this?

for example:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[\"Empty list\"].cells()[\"Page Curl\"].______
```

the app developer told me he's using accessibility type, but im not sure the commands are for this.